# xcode external build system - Shell Script Invocation Error

Tags: xcode5, autoconf, automake, libtool

I am building my makefile project in xcode5 which works perfectly well for the most part. It is a autoconf project with many subdirectories - no big deal.

I do have an issue with the Issue Navigator however. When I have a bug in one of the files somewhere in my project, xcode correctly detects an issue and spits out an error in the Issue Navigator - however it seems xcode cannot link the error to the file in the Project Navigator.

In the example below, I have inserted a junk string in one of the methods "hello" which clearly the compiler is not happy about. Unfortunately, the .cpp file cannot be found even though it's within the project

[image: Screenshot from Issue Navigator]

I suspect that xcode is doing it's best by parsing the output of the makefile/clang++ and trying to determine where the problem is - but clearly failing.

Here are the logs from the Log Navigator

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
Making all in src
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in src/pops
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in src/jops
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in src/jops/tops
/bin/sh ../../../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile clang++ -std=c++11 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../..    -I /usr/include/openssl -I../../../src/ -g -O2 -MT test.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/test.Tpo -c -o test.lo test.cpp
libtool: compile:  clang++ -std=c++11 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../.. -I /usr/include/openssl -I../../../src/ -g -O2 -MT test.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/test.Tpo -c test.cpp  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/test.o
test.cpp:8:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'hello'
        hello
        ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [test.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Can anyone help me help xcode locate the file in the Issue Navigator? It would help me debug this project using the xcode IDE which I really like.

Comment: I have found one hacky solution. In the Makefile.am I specify ${PWD}/ before each .cpp file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the best alternative is to use [Automake in non-recursive mode](https://autotools.io/automake/nonrecursive.html). That will print the path relative to the toplevel directory.